# VB.net Multiple listbox item to same line

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, listbox

How Can I "convert" my listbox items to same line?

example:

1. item1
2. item2
3. item3

>

item1 item2 item3

My extract code for add items to listbox.

```
Dim PageElement As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")

For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElement
    If (CurElement.GetAttribute("id") = "info1") + (CurElement.GetAttribute("id") = "info2") Then
        ListBox2.Items.Add(CurElement.InnerText)
        correct()
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Do you need to perform this operation on the rendered html or could you do this also when initially populating your ListBox? Have you considered doing this on the client side using jQuery?

Comment: initially populating listbox.

Comment: my listbox multiple lines to a single listbox line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:
Define a string:

```
Dim Line As String = ""
```

Then put this code inside the For Loop:

```
Line = Line & CurElement.InnerText & " "
```

And then put this below the For Loop:

```
Line = Line.Remove(Line.Length - 1, 1)
ListBox1.Items.Add(Line)
```